# C#: Func with a constructor of an inherited type

Tags: c#, lambda, constructor, func, inherited

As we know you can point to a constructor as a `Func<T>` like this:

```
Func<MyObject> constructor = () => new MyObject();
var newObject = constructor();
```

But is there a way to make **a constructor for an object you know inherits from MyObject**, but you don't know its exact type?

```
Type inheritedObjectType = obj; // Parameter
Func<MyObject> constructor = () => new MyObject(); // as inheritedObjectType
var newInheritedObject = constructor; // Should now be of the inherited type
```

An answer with using `Activator` or anything returning `Object` is not an option.

**Edit**: I don't know what type the derived type is at compile time. I only have a `System.Type`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use expression trees to build and compile a delegate that will create your derived type:

```
Func<TBase> CreateDelegate<TBase>(Type derived)
{
    var ctor = derived.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);

    if (ctor == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("D'oh! No default ctor.");
    }

    var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TBase>>(
        Expression.New(ctor, new Expression[0]), 
        new ParameterExpression[0]);

    return newExpression.Compile();
}
```

You can simply call it as follows:

```
Func<MyBase> create = CreateDelegate<MyBase>(typeof(Derived));

MyBase instance = create();
```

When you cache that delegate, you will get maximum performance.

Comment: btw: this is exactly what Dependency Injection frameworks will do for you. Most framework will allow a syntax as follows to register: `container.Register(typeof(MyBase), derived)` and you can get a new instance as follows: `container.GetInstance<MyBase>()` et voila.

Answer (score 2):

Does this program exhibit the desired behavior?

```
class MyObject{}
class Derived : MyObject {}
internal class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        // the type you want to construct
        Type type = typeof (Derived);

        MethodInfo getConstructor = MakeConstructorGetter(type);
        Func<MyObject> constructor = (Func<MyObject>)getConstructor.Invoke(null, null);

        var obj = constructor();
        Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType());
    }

    private static MethodInfo MakeConstructorGetter(Type type)
    {
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(Program).GetMethod("GetObjectConstructor", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var getConstructor = mi.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        return getConstructor;
    }

    private static Func<T> GetObjectConstructor<T>() where T : MyObject, new()
    {
        return () => new T();
    }
}
```

`MakeConstructorGetter` will throw an exception if the type described by `Type` does not match the generic constraints. So, this will fail in execution time rather than during compilation, but I guess that is a tradeoff you need to make when dealing with generics dynamically like this.

Comment: I don't know what "Derived" is other than a System.Type.

Comment: @Seb: Updated the answer so that it constructs a generic method for the given `Type`.

Comment: Hmm, the "getConstructor.Invoke" is basically like Activator.CreateInstance and returns an Object. I want to reference the constructor-lambda for performance, which the reflection-based equivalent doesn't quite have. If it can't be done, then that's the correct answer and you're solution is the closest one can get.

Comment: @Seb: note that `getConstructor.Invoke` returns the generic constructor but *does not construct the object*; the object is created by the constructed generic call (so there should be no reflection there). You should easily be able to cache the generated constructors per type.

Comment: Does that actually work? I don't think `getConstructor.Invoke(null, null)` returns a `Func<T>` but simply something that inherits from `MyObject`.

Comment: @Steven: `getConstructor.Invoke` does indeed return a `Func<T>`. There is a lot of syntactic sugar in there, but essentially `return () => new T();` is equivalent of `return new Func<T>(delegate { return new T(); });`